# How to make New Relic Track only one JBoss web app

Tags: newrelic

I currently have 3 web apps running on a single JBoss 7.1 container. I've successfully installed newrelic but it's currently monitoring all 3 web apps. Is there a way to make newrelic only monitor one web app?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good deal of customization available to control what app names traffic is reported to and whether particular transactions are reported to New Relic. But if you're currently seeing three different app names appearing under the 'Applications' menu, the easiest thing to do is just click the gear icon and select 'hide app'

Beyond that, an API call can cause any selected transactions to be ignored by the agent. https://newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-api

And if that doesn't have it resolved, you'll need to open a ticket at support.newrelic.com so we can take a look at your dashboard/setup.